# Live character count for EditText

Tags: android

I was wondering what the best way to do a live character count of an edit-text box is in Android. I was looking at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) but I couldn't seem to make any sense of it.

To describe the problem, I have an EditText and I'm trying to limit the characters to 150. I can do this with an input filter, however I want to show right below the text box the number of characters a user has entered(Almost like stack overflow is doing right now).

If someone could write a small snippet of example code or point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 169):

you can use a TextWatcher to see when the text has changed

```
private TextView mTextView;
private EditText mEditText;
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //This sets a textview to the current length
           mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
};
```

you set the TextWatcher for the edittext with

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Comment: tried this, works great! should be selected as correct answer!

Comment: what would be the best way to add the count say at the bottom right of the text box. Extend edit text and draw the string manually?

Comment: Thanks i too got it, but how to get count down in reverse order like 150,149,148,147.... while entering the text.

Comment: It solved by replacing with this line mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(150-s.length())); in place of mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));

Comment: My problem is similar as @Bear have. I need to show this count down text right below of the edit text. Anybody have anything to share in this reference. Thanks.

Comment: No. This won't work for special character, e.g. ♥, which should be count as 2 characters (on SMS) instead of 1!

Answer (score 125):

You can do character counting from xml itself using [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html?utm_campaign=android_update_important_bug_fixes_101515&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog) wrapper for EditText introduced in [SupportLibrary v23.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html)

Just wrap your EditText with a TextInputLayout and set CounterEnabled to true and Set a counterMaxLength.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="20"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Text Hint"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You'll get a material effect like [this](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-character-counter)

You may use **counterOverflowTextAppearance** , **counterTextAppearance** to style the counter.

**EDIT**

From Android documentation.

The **TextInputEditText** class is provided to be used as a child of this layout. Using TextInputEditText allows TextInputLayout greater control over the visual aspects of any text input. An example usage is as so:

```
     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="@string/form_username"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html?utm_campaign=android_update_important_bug_fixes_101515&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog) [TextInputEditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html)

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for :) a clean, support-library impl. thanks

Comment: Should be the Accepted answer! I totally missed those attributes!

Answer (score 35):

You can do it with `TextInputLayout` and compat libraries with:

```
app:counterEnabled="true"
app:counterMaxLength="420"
```

and complete:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="420">

    <EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:maxLength="420" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Great this worked for me, but how I change the color of counter?

Answer (score 20):

in xml add this attribute for editText

```
    android:maxLength="80"
```

in java add this listener

```
  ed_caption.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            tv_counter.setText(80 - s.toString().length() + "/80");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

Its very Simple Follow the instructions below:

====Add them to your Imports===

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
```

=====Define this=====

```
private TextView sms_count;
```

==========Inside On Create=====

```
sms_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


final TextWatcher txwatcher = new TextWatcher() {
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

      sms_count.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
   }

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }
};

sms_message.addTextChangedListener(txwatcher);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a counter to your TextInputEditText being wrapped in a TextInputLayout. As you can see in the example, `counterEnabled` enables this feature and `counterMaxLengh` defines the number of characters for it.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="50">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    You can use TextWatcher class to see text has changed and how much number of character remains.Here i have set counter of 140 characters.

    EditText typeMessageToPost;
    TextView number_of_character;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundleInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedBundleInstance);
setContentView(R.layout.post_activity);
typeMessageToPost.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
}
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher=new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            number_of_character.setText(String.valueOf(140-s.length()));
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks @RavishSharma :) I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Just set these 2 lines in `TextInputLayout`in your XML file:

```
app:counterEnabled="true"
app:counterMaxLength="200"
```

Comment: Great didn't knew about that. It seems always to be the better solution to wrap an Edittext into a TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses `Kotlin` and shows the number of characters left. Also, if the current number of characters surpasses the limit of 50, the text color will change to red.

**Kotlin**

```
private val mTitleTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if(YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_ID.text.toString().trim().length < 51){
            YOUR_CHAR_LEFT_TEXTVIEW_ID.text = (50 - YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_ID.text.toString().trim().length).toString()
            YOUR_CHAR_LEFT_TEXTVIEW_ID.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        }
        else{
            YOUR_CHAR_LEFT_TEXTVIEW_ID.text = "0"
            YOUR_CHAR_LEFT_TEXTVIEW_ID.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
}
```

Also, don't forget to add the `TextWatcher` to your `EditText`

```
YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_ID.addTextChangedListener(mTitleTextWatcher)
```

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem and I tried Cameron's method. It works but there is a minor bug: If the user use copy and paste then it fails to count the chars. So I suggest to do after the text changed, like below:

```
    private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

         }

         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

         }

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             //This sets a textview to the current length
             mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
         }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:maxLength="140"`

Answer (score 1):

```
     edtmm.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    int data = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.length()));
                    if (data == 2) {
                        edtdd.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        edtmm.requestFocus();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this.

This solution may be more performant as opposed to getting CharSequence.length. Each time you tap on the soft keyboard the event fires; therefore, if you do a length it will count the CharSequence each time, which may slow if you start getting into large CharSequnces.  The event listener on text change tacks the before and after count.  This works well for increment and decrement values

```
@Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
            int tick = start + after;
            if(tick < mMessageMax) {
                int remaining = mMessageMax - tick;
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.contact_us_chars)).setText(String.valueOf(remaining));
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is effect permosrmatce, TextWatcher is best Approach for this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {
        editText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (length < 100) {
                    if (count > 0 && after <= 0)/*remove emoij*/ {
                        length--;
                    } else if (count > after)/*remove text*/ {
                        length--;
                    } else if (count == 0 && after > 1)/*emoij*/ {
                        ++length;
                    } else if (count == 0 && after == 1)/*Text*/ {
                        ++length;
                    } else if (count > 0 && after > 1) {
                        ++length;
                    }
                    if (s.length() <= 0)
                        length = 0;
                    Log.w("MainActivity", " Length: " + length);
                } else {
                    if (count > 0 && after <= 0)/*remove emoij*/ {
                        length--;
                    } else if (count > after)/*remove text*/ {
                        length--;
                    }
                    Log.w("MainActivity", " Length: " + length);
                }

                if (length == 100) {
                    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(s.length())});
                } else {
                    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{});
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Clear way;

```
abstract class CharacterWatcher : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {
        afterCharacterChanged(text?.lastOrNull(), text?.length)
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, before: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    abstract fun afterCharacterChanged(char: Char?, count: Int?)
}



 editText.addTextChangedListener(new CharacterWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterCharacterChanged(@Nullable Character character, @Nullable Integer count) {
                action()
            }
        });
```