# Problems with mTextEditorWatcher on Android

Tags: android

Sorry for the previous "Why Android is such a mess?" question. I'm just overwhelmed with the little problem here. I'm trying to make a char. counter on an EditText:

```
final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        EditText edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        TextView text_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    };

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       //This sets a textview to the current length
       text_view.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
    };

    //public void afterTextChanged1(Editable s) {
    //};

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    };
};
```

And then it crashes. This is why I actually was asking about EditText/TextView claims earlier. I don't get what's wrong with this code?

LogCat log:

```
04-23 00:57:46.029: E/AndroidRuntime(347): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dtype.writer/com.dtype.writer.DTypeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1612)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at com.dtype.writer.DTypeActivity$1.<init>(DTypeActivity.java:29)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at com.dtype.writer.DTypeActivity.<init>(DTypeActivity.java:28)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
04-23 00:57:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(347):  ... 11 more
04-23 00:57:46.128: E/dalvikvm(347): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

This solution was borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455667/1349940) and Cameron Ketcham suggests using `mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);` to set the TextWatcher to the EditText. May it be the core of my problem?

Update 4/24/2012: still haven't found any working solution for this one.

Comment: Please post the error log (log cat output).

Comment: Try rebuilding your resources. Looks like the `textView1` can't be found, which could mean your resource file is out of sync.

Comment: I borrowed solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013791/live-character-count-for-edittext-android) and Cameron Ketcham suggests putting `mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);`, could absence of it in my code cause this crash? And yeah, resources seems to be synced.

Comment: The problem with `mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);` for me is to decide in what part of the code this line should go.

Comment: you can't use `findViewById` in the constructor, your activity is not ready then and there are no views to find yet. Move all that code into `onCreate` for example, including the `addTextChangedListener` part

Answer (score 4):

I think that is because you put:

> mTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

when it have to be:

> mTextView = (**TextView**) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Answer (score 2):

Should work in about that way.

```
private TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher;
private EditText mEditText; 
private TextView mTextView;

public void onCreate() {
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    };

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       //This sets a textview to the current length
       mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
    }

    //public void afterTextChanged1(Editable s) {
    //}

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
  };
  mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
}
```

Comment: Partially moved the code to `OnCreate` as you suggested. Still no luck with the launch.

Comment: did the error messaged change? The important part is to move `findViewById` so it is not executed before `onCreate` is called.

Comment: Actually yes. `at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1612)` disappeared from the log. Rest of the errors remain.