# How to find whether the soft keyboard is visible state or in non visible state in Android

Tags: android

Am  trying to show the count for edittext when user enters text in edittext for that i need to find whether the keyboard is in visible state are not . If keyboard is in visible state then only i need to show text length.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how can i tell if the soft keyboard is showing or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568919/android-how-can-i-tell-if-the-soft-keyboard-is-showing-or-not)

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Comment: for character count:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013791/live-character-count-for-edittext-android