# How to add Character counter to SMS APP?

Tags: android

I was create a simple sms sending app. In this app i want to  add a text counter . How to do this ? The total character limit is 164. Please anybody help me to do this.

Comment: Do you currently have any code?  What potential solutions have you thought about?

Comment: Check the length of EditText using EditText.getText().length()<=164 prior sending your message.

Comment: kind of the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013791/live-character-count-for-edittext-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add below code

```
edtCustomerSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCustomerSearch);
edtCustomerSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("TAG","lenth: "+edtCustomerSearch.getText().toString().length());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First set Max length for your EditText like ,`android:maxLength="164"`

Now you have to validate length of EditText while user typing the message and that is possible using `TextWatcher Class & addTextChangedListener Listener`.

Now make simple easy function to validate your input text as below,

```
public void Check_SMS_Length(EditText edt) throws NumberFormatException {
            try {
            if (edt.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                            edt.setError("Sorry...!! Its Mandatory Field");
                            valid_len = 0;
                            tv.setText("0/164");

                        } else {
                            valid_len = edt.getText().toString().length();
                            tv.setText(String.valueOf(valid_len) + "/" + 164);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("error", "" + e);
                    }

                }
```

And call this function in `afterTextChanged`.

```
edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Check_SMS_Length(edt); // pass your EditText Obj here.
    }
});
```

How it will looks ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for this would be a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). It is an interface which has 3 methods that you can use to perform actions before, during, and after text is being changed. You can add this interface to any editable object such as an EditText.

```
TextWatcher TextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max Number of characters for your edit text in the xml properties of edit text as shown below:

```
android:maxLength="164"
```

Further, for dynamically counting the number of character in your text field you can use the below code:

```
//Global counter variable
final int counter=0;

//For your edit text, set a text change listener as shown below

EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                try {
                   counter=count;
                   if(counter>164)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Max length reached",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

This helped me. Hope it helps you too.