# Android : create count down word field when user type in EditText

Tags: android

I would like like to show in a `TextView` a counter which decrease following the number of character that the user write in an EditText.

I have one `TextView` to show the counter from 110 characters, 109, 108, 107 ....

```
wordCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nouvelle_annonce_words_count) ;
```

And i have an Editext where the user write :

```
title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nouvelle_annonce_titre) ;
```

How can i listen the change in my EditText and update my textView with the number of character remaining ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Live Character Count For EditText Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013791/live-character-count-for-edittext-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `addTextChangedListener` like this

```
title.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      wordCount.setText(String.valueOf(110 - (title.getText().toString().length)));
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is called a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
title.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            wordCount.setText(String.valueOf(110-s.length()));
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```