# Can I take key input from other view than the one being edited?

Tags: android, interface

There are two views A and B, the user is typing in view B, but A wants to know what the user types, is this possible in android? The view B can be any view(we don't know which one exactly). There can be many views B, we don't know which one is going to be changed, so I want a general way of reading key inputs from any other view

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using `TextWatcher`, as shown in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455667/6254066

Answer (score 0):

Are the two views editText? If yes. Then you can do this by setting text by implementing **addTextChangedListener** on the first editText. It is implemented as follows.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        doSomething(); // Add text to second editText



    } 

});
```

Comment: sorry, but want a general answer in which which edittext is being given input is not known

Comment: So you could you use the above code and apply it both and thn in onTextChanged of both you can just add to the other editText. It would do the thing for you. Let me know if you got it.

Answer (score 0):

you can take two view one is EditText and other is TextView

in EditText add TextChangedListener

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence myText, int start, int before, int count) {

    textView.setText(myText); // change Textview value



} 

});
```

for better understanding try this one 
http://javatechig.com/android/android-textwatcher-example