# Dynamic Word Count for EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I am trying to get the Dynamic Or Live word count for an Edit Text.
To explain the problem, I have an EditText and a Textview inside a fragment, whenever the user enters a sentence in the EditText it should automatically count the number of words occurring in that sentence and display the number of words in the TextView.

I have implemented the Text Watcher but can't figure out the code snippet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013791/live-character-count-for-edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the callbacks of a `TextWatcher` is `afterTextChanged(Editable edit)`.

A `Editable` is what you get when you call `getText` on an `EditText`, which holds the current text, and therefore also knows the length of the current text.

So you can do something like this:

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            ...
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String currentText = editable.toString();
                int currentLength = currentText.length();
                textView.setText("Current length: " + currentLength);
            }
        });
```

Comment: this code is returning the count of number of characters, I need the count of number of words entered in the editText..

Comment: Then split the currentText with a space and use .length on the returned array. That's how many words there are in the entire text.

Comment: It's NOT working when you have single words separated by returns.