# I want to count live input character from EditText in java

Tags: android

I want to count live character count from editext in java and maximum keyword will is 160

Comment: this is a very poorly asked question. It'll be closed soon I guess, but do research `TextWatcher`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live character count for EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013791/live-character-count-for-edittext)

Comment: Use addTextChangedListener to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addTextChangedListener` like this

```
 edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               int count = edtText.getText().toString().length();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```