# How to know if user is typing something in an Edittext (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keylistener

So the idea is to check if the user is typing anything and then take that text length and show it somewhere. I used the max length attribute to limit the user entering big text, but I also want it to be showed for the user. This picture will make things clear-
[image: Edittext]

I don't know how to listen for key pressed. I just want to take the text every time user types one character even space or backspace, I want to take the text, get the length of it and show it below. Is there any way to that? What's the way to listen for key pressing in Java?

I tried to use setOnKeyListener, but it didn't work, or I couldn't understand how it works. How to do this specific part programatically? The code I wrote, though I know it's wrong-

```
binding.about.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Key Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ah yes! It worked. Thanks. Could you provide the link as an answer or give an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use the following snippet

```
binding.edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      // when text is changed in edittext
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This here answers my question perfectly. [Live character count for EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013791/live-character-count-for-edittext)